# Oracle xml_dom.writeToClob returning wrong character set

Tags: xml, oracle, encoding

I am trying to convert XML to CLOB and save it in table. Version of DB is Oracle 9.2.0.8. 
This is how I am creating XML.

```
DECLARE    
    p               dbms_xmlparser.parser;
    xml_doc         dbms_xmldom.domdocument;
BEGIN

    p := dbms_xmlparser.newParser;
    dbms_xmlparser..parseBuffer(p, '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="'||codepage||'"?><elm/>');
    d := dbms_xmlparser.getDocument(p);
    ...
END;
```

But after converting XML to CLOB the cyrilic characters becoming not readable in variable v_xml_clob:

```
v_xml_clob    clob;
DBMS_LOB.createtemporary (v_xml_clob, TRUE);
dbms_xmldom.writeToClob(xml_doc , v_xml_clob);
```

But when I write XML to file all is OK: `dbms_xmldom.writeToFile(xml_doc , PATH);`
And this is the example of text which is becoming wrong:

```
Сберегательные депозиты резидентов - национальная валюта
is becoming
бсх№хурђхыќэћх фхяючшђћ №хчшфхэђют - эрішюэрыќэрџ трыўђр
```

Please help me to fix this.

Comment: The original bytes are encoded in Windows-1251, but in the result they are treated as ISO-8859-5. Does that help? You could look those up somewhere in your code, you are not showing them.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it this way:

```
v_xml_clob := convert(v_xml_clob,'CL8ISO8859P5','CL8MSWIN1251');
```